# Create a View in Oracle with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I am trying to create a view that has both my strSupplierName column from my tblSuppliers table as well as my strProductName column from my tblProducts table, and have been having some trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE  "tblSuppliers" 
   (    "lngSupplierID" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strSupplierName" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strSupplierAddressStreet" VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strSupplierAddressCity" VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strSupplierAddressCountry" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strSupplierAddressPostCode" VARCHAR2(25), 
    "strSupplierPhoneNo" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strSupplierFaxNo" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "strPaymentTerms" VARCHAR2(500), 
     CONSTRAINT "tblSuppliers_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("lngSupplierID") ENABLE
   ) ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_tblSuppliers" 
  before insert on "tblSuppliers"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."lngSupplierID" is null then 
    select "TBLSUPPLIERS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."lngSupplierID" from dual; 
  end if; 
end; 


CREATE TABLE  "strProducts" 
   (    "lngProductID" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "strProductName" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "chkInStock" VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "lngUnitsInStock" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "curProductUnitPurchasePrice" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "curProductUnitSalePrice" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "lngSupplierID" VARCHAR2(100), 
     CONSTRAINT "tblProducts_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("lngProductID") ENABLE
   ) ;

ALTER TABLE  "tblProducts" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("lngSupplierID")
      REFERENCES  "tblSuppliers" ("lngSupplierID") ENABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_tblProducts" 
  before insert on "tblProducts"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."lngProductID" is null then 
    select "TBLPRODUCTS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."lngProductID" from dual; 
  end if; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_tblProducts" ENABLE;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of your tables. I mean, c'mon - remote mind-reading technology is still in its infancy...  :-)

Comment: By definitions do you mean the SQL code for the tables?

Comment: Dont mean to be ambiguous, I've provided the names of the columns I have created ,and involved in the view, as well as the name of their respective tables. Please let me know what else is needed and what is meant by definitions.

Comment: @Jay Yes, definitions means exactly what you posted.  The triggers are probably irrelevant to your problem, but it's hard to say since you don't explain what your problem actually is.  "Having some trouble" doesn't help anyone understand where you are going wrong.  It sounds like you probably have  a CREATE VIEW statement that is giving you an error; if so, please also post that statement and what the error is you are getting.

Comment: @Jay ,You say, "trying to create" , but have not posted the view statement, please post that and any error relating to it you have received.

Comment: Where is the `create view` statement that you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
CREATE VIEW "yourViewName" AS
SELECT
 p."lngProductID",
 p."strProductName",
 s."lngSupplierID",
 s."strSupplierName"
FROM "strProducts" p
INNER JOIN "tblSuppliers" s ON s."lngSupplierID" = p."lngSupplierID"
```

Comment: Used this but modified the last strProducts to be tblProducts worked great!